# Remove previous cart items when logged in during checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to delete all old cart items if the user logs in during checkout.
For example:
a. User adds 3 items some days ago

> - Cap
>      - Ball
>     - Keyring

b. Then he logged out and today he adds some items in cart to purchase.

> - Hoodie
>      - Mobile Phone

He is asked to login during checkout and the cart shows 4 products.

> - Cap
>      - Ball
>     - Keyring
>  
>       - Hoodie
>      - Mobile Phone

How to only show the two latest product and deleted the old ones.

> - Hoodie
>      - Mobile Phone

I added the following code to my `functions.php` but it deletes all previously added products form all the pages.

```
function clear_persistent_cart_after_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . $blog_id ) ) {
        delete_user_meta( $user->ID, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . $blog_id );
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'clear_persistent_cart_after_login', 10, 2);
```

I only want them to be deleted when logged in from checkout page. I also tried using permalink but it didn't work.

 Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce - Remove all old cart items if logged in during checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783343/woocommerce-remove-all-old-cart-items-if-logged-in-during-checkout)

Comment: @MujeebuRahman Yes. The question has not been answered